# Can my Home PC Handle the Lucas-Lehmer Test by Itself? (or Do I Need GIMPS)

Tags: number-theory, primality-test, computer-arithmetic, lucas-lehmer-test

Last year, the largest Mersenne prime $2^{82,589,933}$ that we now know of was discovered. It contains almost $25,000,000$ digits if expanded out. I do not understand much how GIMPS operates, other than it makes use of the Lucas-Lehmer test algorithm.

My question might be naive, but I ask it anyway: On a PC with 8GB of RAM, am I capable of running the Lucas-Lehmer test on a Mersenne number $M_{p}$ with a prime $p$ of my choice? In theory, I certainly could recursively compute the $(n-1)st$ term of the underlying *extended Lucas sequence* sequence that GIMPS uses and attempt to divide my chosen $M_{p}$ into it. But can little computers like mine handle such large numbers?

Comment: Read the section "Details on the Discovery and Verification" on https://www.mersenne.org/primes/press/M82589933.html . You should be able to check it on your computer, but even with the most optimal implementation of the test it will likely require a week or more worth of computing to complete on a modern CPU.

Comment: At first GIMPS is just an implementation of large numbers, LLT (and FFT multiplication of integers) plus a server telling you a list of unchecked or to be verified $p$. With pari-gp you can implement LLT-FFT in a few lines

Comment: For a short proof of LLT you can look [there](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_de_primalit%C3%A9_de_Lucas-Lehmer_pour_les_nombres_de_Mersenne#Preuve)

Comment: @reuns Would you happen to have that few lines of code? I am not very experienced with PARI/GP but would like to get better at it, Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LLT implementation in Pari/gp

```
    p = 19937; Mp = 2^p-1; x = 4; 

    moduloM(p,n) = { a= shift(n,-p); b = n-shift(a,p); r = b+a; };
    for(n=1, p-2, x = moduloM(p,moduloM(p,x^2-2))); 

    /* slow version :  
       x = Mod(4,Mp); for(n=1, p-2, x = x^2-2); */

    if(x == Mp, print("2^",p,"-1 is prime"), print("2^",p,"-1 is NOT PRIME"));
```

Comment: you can do mod mp with shifts and adds.

Comment: I replaced `Mod(x^2-2,Mp)` by a shift & add and it is much faster now, 2 seconds to check $2^{19937}-1$ is prime, so I guess it uses fft multiplication (in the doc they say they use gmp whose doc suggests fft multiplication is automatic for large numbers)

Comment: I will need 6 hours to check $M34 = 2^{1257787}-1$ and adding `default("parisizemax", 400000000)` to the code we can check the largest Mersenne prime $2^{82589933}-1$ for which it will take 955 days (for such large primes GIMPS probably stores intermediate values on its server)

Comment: I only know that, because I once made a thread about fast versions of LL on the GIMPS forum.

Comment: You can also rip off the last p bits of your value. Just mod by $2^p$ and you can use 3,p as your iteration count, no $p-2$ required.

Comment: I don't see what you mean, in moduloM  $b = (n \bmod 2^p)$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96114/discussion-between-roddy-macphee-and-reuns).

Answer (score 2):

$25$ million digits is large but within reach of some number theory tools like pari/gp or maple.

So, in principle, you can check such a number with a single normal computer.

Of course, it will take long until the number is checked.

Note that the calculations that have to be done do not exceed the $50$ million digits mark.

Comment: Thank you. I have used PARI/GP for other things but when I try to set the precision too high, such as when working with long decimals of extremely small numbers, it gives me error messages. I guess I'm presuming I'll have the same problem with very large numbers too.

Comment: For integers, you need not set a precision, the only problem can be the memory.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. Thank you again.

Comment: For long integers problems I propose to use the 64-bit-processor-version of Pari/GP. Often much faster and more efficiently using memory than the standard version for 32-bit processors, it seems to me.

Comment: you can limit the residue by mapping to equivalent residues saving bits on the squaring.